# deleting an element in a vector of pointer

Tags: c++

I just want to make sure if this is the right way to delete an allocated memory where there exist an element in the vector that pointing to that object;

```
vector<Fruit*> temp;
```

let say if the sixth element in the vector is pointing to the object that I want to delete.

```
Fruit* a = temp[5];
temp.erase(temp.begin()+5);
delete a;
```

is this right? thx

Comment: Sure. Or even just `delete temp[5]; temp.erase(temp.begin() + 5);`.

Comment: okay thx. I just want to make sure that I do the right thing :D

Answer (score 2):

The Kerrek's suggestion is of course OK:

```
delete temp[5];
temp.erase(temp.begin() + 5);
```

I'm writing an answer, however, to suggest you think about smart pointers. Here's an example:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Fruit>> v;

// add some elements

v.erase(temp.begin() + 5);
```

In this case, there's no memory leak, because `shared_ptr` destruction deletes the object owned by it, or decreases the number of references properly. If there's no shared ownership involved, you can just use `unique_ptr`. `boost::ptr_vector` might also come in handy.

Comment: `unique_ptr` makes more sense here than `shared_ptr`, as there is no need for shared ownership.